# Bubble getting cut off in Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I'm having an issue where the last bubble in my chart cuts off. I need a way of extending the chart so that the entire circle is displayed. I've tried everything from adding an extra value to the end, to adjusting padding. Nothing seems to work. Unfortunately, the Chart JS documention on bubble charts is severely lacking as well.

```
var randomScalingFactor = function() {
  return (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1.0 : -1.0) * Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
};
var randomColorFactor = function() {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
};
var randomColor = function() {
  return 'rgba(' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + randomColorFactor() + ',.7)';
};

var bubbleChartData = {
  animation: {
    duration: 10000
  },
  datasets: [{
    label: "My First dataset",
    backgroundColor: randomColor(),
    data: [
      {
        x: 10,
        y: 0,
        r: Math.abs(randomScalingFactor()) / 5,
      }, {
        x: 20,
        y: 0,
        r: Math.abs(randomScalingFactor()) / 5,
      }, {
        x: 30,
        y: 0,
        r: Math.abs(randomScalingFactor()) / 5,
      }, {
        x: 40,
        y: 0,
        r: Math.abs(randomScalingFactor()) / 5,
      }, {
        x: 50,
        y: 0,
        r: Math.abs(randomScalingFactor()) / 5,
      }, {
        x: 60,
        y: 0,
        r: Math.abs(randomScalingFactor()) / 5,
      }, {
        x: 70,
        y: 0,
        r: 30,
      }]
  }]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById('Chart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bubble',
  data: bubbleChartData
})
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3dog0bec/

[image: Padding issue]

Comment: Have you tried to increase the x-scale?

Comment: Or add an empty (zero) value at the end of data to create en extra invisible bubble but this is a hack

Comment: I did try adding a zero value at the end, but it still shows up as a very small bubble. Not ideal. Increasing the x scale may work, is there any documentation on this?

Comment: I had a quick look but could not find the exact option but you need to look at scale increment value and x scale max. Could be an x step problem. Try playing with the x scale steps in chart options. Not sure if it will help.

Comment: Will do. I've also added a JSFiddle for an example. I'll create a ticket in Github.

Comment: Change the increment to 20 for example should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue by modifying the xAxes ticks min and max. This worked because I have a set number of data to display, so I simply set the values to 10 less than the first data point and 10 more than the last.

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bubble',
        data: bubbleChartData,
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [
                {
                    ticks: {
                        min: -10,
                        max: 100
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This approach works well, but when using a percent scale, it looks insane a bit.